# Python horizontal bar plotly not showig the whole range of timestamp data

Tags: python, plotly

I want to plot the data availability using pyplot. I got the code from @vestland. My monthly data is [here](https://gofile.io/?c=cQNB3O).
In general, the data spans from January 2009 to January 2019. Each variable comes with its own time period.
Below is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

path  = r'C:\Users\....\availability3.txt'
df  = pd.read_csv(path)
df  = df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)

fig = px.bar(df, x="Timestamp", y="variable", color='value', orientation='h',
             hover_data=["Timestamp"],
             height=300,
             color_continuous_scale=['firebrick', '#2ca02c'],
             title='Data Availabiltiy Plot',
             template='plotly_white',
            )

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title=''), 
                  xaxis=dict(
                      title='', 
                      showgrid=True, 
                      gridcolor='white',
                      tickvals=[]
                  )
                 )
fig.show()
```

As you can see below, the plot shows only the first row of the data which is the first day.

[image]

What I want is to show the whole range of the data on the x axis with corresponding values and colors. The result should show data from January 2009 to January 2019, variable values of 0 is shown on red and 1 in green.

Perhaps this is an issue with timestamp, because when using the number index, the plot is just okay.

**Edit**
By removing duplicates in the dataset and set timestamp as index, I got an almost the expected result. This the new code.

```
fig = px.bar(df, y="variable", color='value', orientation='h',
             hover_data=[df.index],
             height=300,
             color_continuous_scale=['firebrick', '#2ca02c'],
             title='Data Availabiltiy Plot',
             template='plotly_white',
            )
```

Now the whole time span is showing as expected. But the value of x-axis timestamp is not yet showing. I will ask in another post

Answer (score 1):

I checked the documentation for `plotly.express.bar` and briefly worked with your code.  Your data may be stacked one on top of each other.

Setting `orientation='v'` shows all of the data, but not in any particularly intuitive way, although I believe it does answer the question you asked.  Yes, the data for `Alice, Thalia, Citra, and Pebaru` are all present, but the `y-axis` needs modification to get the proper labels:

[image]

Alternatively, setting `orientation='h'` and `barmode='overlay'` shows all of the data when you hover, but not as individual bars. You can see the overlay blur on the right edge of the bars:

[image]

There are quite a few arguments for `plotly.express.bar` in the documentation:  https://plot.ly/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar.html#plotly.express.bar.  Experiment around and see what you can come up with.

EDIT:

1) Set the `x-axis` independently using the `Timeframe` column.

2) Use `.groupby()` with an averaging function on `value`.